# How can I recover a corrupted PowerPoint 2010 file?

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, file-corruption

I have a corrupted PowerPoint 2010 file that I need to recover ASAP!

Are there any free recovery tools out there for this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes! Restoring from your regular backups costs nothing and you can start work again immediately after the restore is complete. Everybody knows to make regular backups of important things and it appears that since this file is important you would have backed it up regularly.

Comment: this was something that I created today therefore it was not included in last night's backup

Answer (score 1):

There are rarely free tools for problems like this, and I could find none. You can try following this Microsoft document "Recover a corrupt PowerPoint file":

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/recover-a-corrupt-powerpoint-file-HA001116878.aspx?redir=0

Comment: I tried following the instructions in this tutorial with no avail.  Are there any other suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.pptx files are actually zip files. So are .xlsx and .docx.  [Infozip's](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html) zip.exe has the following command line options:

```
-F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder)
```

I'd make a copy of the corrupt file and try using `zip -F file.pptx` and/or `zip -FF file.pptx`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem - try opening it in Open Office and re-naming the file.  Worked for me :)